# When Radio Button is selected, check and disabled checkbox

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm still learning jquery but this is what I want

If the radio button with the value of '16' is selected I want the checkbox with the class newsletter selected and then made unable to uncheck.

If the radio button with the value 16 is deselected I want to be able to once again use the checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML, I'm assuming a simple case. Here's some short jQuery to do what you asked for:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    $('input.newsletter').attr({
        'checked': $(this).val() == 16,
        'disabled': $(this).val() == 16
    });
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8J5y9/)**.

Comment: Brilliant, +1 because it's very generic

Comment: Very nice... is there any way to modify it so if the 17 radio button is selected it does not uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: You could change the checked attribute from the above to `        'checked': $(this).val() == 16 || $('input.newsletter').attr('checked')!=undefined,`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8J5y9/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=radio][name=<your radio button set name here>]").changed( function () {
    if ($("input[type=radio][name=<your radio button set name here>]").val() == "16") {
        $("input[type=checkbox].newsletter").attr('checked', 'checked');
        $("input[type=checkbox].newsletter").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //this is one way to make it not unselectable
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=checkbox].newsletter").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

Another way to make it not able to be unselected is in the place of the 2nd line in under the `if` above (the one with the comment next to it) put `stayChecked = true;` and put `stayChecked = false;` in place of the `$(...).removeAttr('disabled');`. Then make another function like the following:

```
$("input[type=checkbox].newsletter").changed( function () {
    if (stayChecked) {
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
});
```

Note: you should either declare `var stayChecked` somewhere outside the two functions on a common level (i.e. on the script level or inside the parent function if they are declared inside, let's say, the $(document).ready() function).